# Custom metrics using Micrometer is not available in Prometheus endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, gauge, micrometer

I'm using Micrometer in Java Spring Boot 1.5 application to scrape custom metrics for Prometheus.

I'm using "guageCollectionSize" method to count the number of entries in a HashMap. When I print the guage value, I'm getting the correct output as expected. But the problem is that I'm not able to view the custom metric in /prometheus endpoint.

Please find the code below

```
private Map<String, String> _strings;
private MeterRegistry registry;
_strings = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
_strings.put("Test","Test");
_strings.put("Test2","Test");
registry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);

registry.gaugeCollectionSize("strings_count", Tags.empty(),_strings.keySet());
System.out.println(registry.get("strings_count").gauge().value());
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you on [the GitHub issue](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/738) which you created on the project repository, you're creating your own `PrometheusMeterRegistry` but you should use the auto-configured one.

I created [a sample](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/blob/gh-738/src/main/java/com/izeye/sample/web/SampleController.java#L26-L37) that uses the auto-configured one and added [a test](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/blob/gh-738/src/test/java/com/izeye/sample/SpringBootActuatorMetricsPrometheusTests.java) for it.